# Use mist with scene that has world texture/background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, world

Is it possible to use mist in a Cycles scene in addition to a world background?

Answer (score 7):

First, [set a world background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5681/add-a-panoramic-background-to-scene-in-cycles).

Then, go to the Render context in Properties and enable `Transparent` (in the `Film` panel).

Create two render layers.  For the first one, enable `Mist` (in the `Passes` panel).  For the second render layer, disable `Combined` and `Z`, and enable `Environment`.  Also, under `Exclude`, select all layers (we only want the background texture).

Create this node setup:

[image: Node Setup]

The value in the `Multiply` node controls the strength of the mist.  The result is:

[image]

(my settings in the Mist Pass panel of World context were `Start`:20, `Depth`:1000, `Falloff`:Linear)

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to do it, especially if you don't want to set up a world background or use world geometry, is to use a simple plane with an image texture at the back of your scene and a color ramp for the mist effect in compositing. If the last color of your ramp is black, then the mist won't apply at the background.

[image: Mist effect]