# Full spherical view inside Blender Game from Pre-Rendered images

Tags: game-engine

Ever played [Myst IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myst_IV:_Revelation)? Most of the game visuals are pre-rendered and you move in a discrete fashion. However, you have the ability to turn the camera 360ºH and 180ºV with your mouse.

I want to accomplish that inside Blender Game using still images renderer in Blender Cycles. What's the most direct, no frills workflow to achieve such thing?

Answer (score 3):

You can render straight to a panorama/full dome image from Cycles by simply adjusting the camera type to Panoramic.

[image]

Then you can UV map the rendered image onto a sphere in the BGE and use a mouse-look controller to allow the player to look around it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the players position is fixed you could create an animation and rotate the camera say in 5° steps horizontally (72 frames) then repeat this process with added vertical rotation (36 frames). You would need to render 72*36 = 2592 frames. Hm, this seems to require too much space on disk and time to load.

Next idea would be to render a panorama.

- [Add a panoramic background to scene in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5681/add-a-panoramic-background-to-scene-in-cycles)

Then use this in the BGE as described here:
[BGE / Creating 360 Video Panorama Viewer](http://blendersushi.blogspot.de/2012/10/bge-creating-360-video-panorama-viewer.html)