# Legacy file in BI: Background image does not change as camera pans

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am working on an older file with a background image. In the animation, the camera moves and pans relative to two objects in the scene. But the background image behind the camera and behind the objects looks the same at every point: The background image is not effected by the move/pan.

I know this solution for Cycles:
[Add a panoramic background to scene in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5681/add-a-panoramic-background-to-scene-in-cycles)

and it performs (in cycles) as I expect: the background image changes as the camera moves/pans... I am unable to recreate this in BI... and clearly I have forgotten something.

All input welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is mapping option in the world texture setting change it from View to what suits your needs :

[image]

Comment: Thank you.... and in fact I had been working with that setting, but did not get any results. In each setting, the camera pan delivers the same background image... I am going to rebuild this file in cycles.... I have tried the background in cycles using the Environmental Texture and mapping nodes.... I wonder if this file is so old it does not work with 2.7x?  Anyway... thanks, and I will move it into Cycles...